# How to Draw a 3D Scatter Plot Graph

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, charts

Firstly: I am completely new to Mathematica, but I need to be able to create a 3D Scatter Graph with the following points:

{0.000824, 15.8, 39.0}, 
{0.000507, 20.5, 39.6}, 
{0.000444, 20.5, 39.8}, 
{0.000380, 20.4, 40.8}, 
{0.000317, 22.0, 40.9}

I also want the axes labelled: {"Oxygen Concentration","Temperature","Salinity"}

The things that I also want are each of the points labelled from P1 to P5 respictively. I would also like the different colours for each point as well as the axis gridlines.

It would be a great help if someone could do this. What I have done so far is:

`ListPointPlot3D[{{0.000824, 15.8, 39.0}, {0.000507, 20.5, 
   39.6}, {0.000444, 20.5, 39.8}, {0.000380, 20.4, 40.8}, {0.000317, 
   22.0, 40.9}}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Oxygen Concentration", "Salinity", "Temperature"}, 
 Boxed -> False, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = {{0.000824, 15.8, 39.0}, {0.000507, 20.5, 39.6}, {0.000444, 20.5, 39.8}, 
        {0.000380, 20.4, 40.8}, {0.000317, 22.0, 40.9}};
bcdata = {##, 1} & @@@ data;
labels = Style["P" <> #, 16, Bold] & /@ CharacterRange["1", "5"];

BubbleChart3D[bcdata, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, FaceGrids -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Oxygen Concentration", "Salinity", "Temperature"}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &), ChartLabels -> labels]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wonderful effect. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
point = {{0.000824, 15.8, 39.0}, {0.000507, 20.5, 39.6}, {0.000444, 
    20.5, 39.8}, {0.000380, 20.4, 40.8}, {0.000317, 22.0, 40.9}};
Graphics3D[{{Red, 
   MapIndexed[Text["P" <> ToString[First[#2]], #1 + {0, .2, 0}] &, 
    point]}, PointSize[.01], Point[point]}, Boxed -> True, 
 PlotRange -> CoordinateBounds[point, {2, .5, .5}], Axes -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], 
 AxesLabel -> {"Oxygen Concentration", "Salinity", "Temperature"}]
```

[image]

Maybe this can help.